# In the iPhone app, how do you turn off incoming calls and set it to go direct to voice mail?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the iPhone app, how do you turn off incoming calls and set it to go direct to voice mail?
(I don't want the phone to interrupt an app in progress. )

thanks

Comment: You can't and even if you somehow could Apple wouldn't allow it

Comment: In the appDelegate, nothing can be done?